# JavaScript: Passing no parameter if option doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I know the answer should be obvious but for some reason i'm having trouble finding a clean  way to do this.

In this example im using a wrapper library around a built in requests library (It handles default headers/auth things like that)

In my smaller client libraries im further wrapping this up by abstracting specific request calls to functions (These functions call the parent wrapper library).

Anyways occasionally to test invalid authorization I need to overwrite the "default" headers that get put into my wrapper library.

My wrapper library handles this like so (for example the `GET` request):

```
public async get(
    url: string,
    headers: any = {}
  ):
```

And further down I check the headers like so:

```
if (Object.keys(headers).length === 0) {
//set headers here
```

and then further down I do the normal call. `get(url, { headers: headers })`

(Maybe there is a better way to handle this, but it works because I can pass along headers OR use the default ones if none are passed)

In my `Client` code. I do something like:

```
public async getWidgets(headers?) {
    let getResponse: APIResponse;
    getResponse = await super.get(SOME_URL, headers ?? null );
    return getResponse;
  }
```

Essentially I am trying to call the parent `GET` with either the default headers if NOTHING is sent OR use the headers that were passed along in the function parameters.

I could do an if/else but im sure there is a cleaner way using ternary maybe? Maybe do something like `getWidget(headers = null)` and then do something like `super.get(SOME_URL, headers ?? null)` problem is I need to make sure the parent uses the default "No headers" if no headers were sent here either. Im not sure if `null` in a parameter is the same as "Nothing" if that makes sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'm not sure why you can't do this?

```
public async getWidgets(headers?) {
    let getResponse: APIResponse;
    getResponse = await super.get(SOME_URL, headers ?? {} );
    return getResponse;
}
```

If headers is specified, then it gets used, otherwise you pass in your empty object.

If this doesn't work, let me know which case is not being handled so I can understand the scenario better

Comment: I thought about that, I guess that should work. I wonder if there is a better way of checking an empty "option" other than `if (Object.keys(headers).length === 0)`

Comment: Believe it or not, but `Object.keys(value).length === 0` is the way to do it.   I've seen some people do `JSON.stringify(value) === '{}'`, but I'm not a fan.

Comment: Feels ugly, but hey if it works! I figured there would be some nicer looking way to check for an empty object

Comment: @msmith1114 although there's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it, one coding pattern that I follow is to avoid objects having optional properties as a general rule.   So in this particular case, I actually would have used null or undefined as the default value instead of an empty object.    If you follow the rule that a given object always has the same set of properties, but their values change (and try to avoid varying the data types of the properties, too), then the JIT will more likely detect that this is in fact a real object rather than a hash-table, and more likely to optimize it.

Comment: I ended up setting the default on the client functions `headers = null` but you are saying that in the wrapper function I should do the same as well?